# IIS: RequireSSL false for an HTTPS binding

Tags: ssl, iis, https

In an IIS website with https binding only, I go to SSL settings:

What is the diference between having RequireSSL setting true or false?

Answer (score 0):

From here (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates):

> - The IIS 7.0 admin tool has an "SSL Settings" node that you can select for each site, directory or file that allows you to control whether that particular resource (and by default its children) requires an SSL request in order to execute.  This is useful for pages like a login.aspx page, where you want to guarantee that users can only enter their credentials when they are posting via an encrypted channel. If you configure the login.aspx page to require SSL, IIS 7.0 will block browsers from accessing it unless they are doing so over SSL.
> - Within an ASP.NET page or handler, you can programmatically check whether the current request is using SSL by checking the Request.IsSecure property (it will return "true" if the incoming browser request is over SSL).
> - You can set the "requireSSL" attribute on the  configuration section within web.config files to have ASP.NET's forms-authentication system ensure that forms-authentication cookies are only set and used on SSL enabled pages and URLs.  This avoids the risk of a hacker trying to intercept the authentication cookie on a non-SSL secured page, and then trying to use a "replay attack" from a different machine to impersonate a user.

So it seems this setting only makes sense when a website has http and https bindings to distinguish which particular resource requires https or not at all.